# Return Server Memory Useage

Tags: php

I have googled and found on here the code to return my server memory usage however I am getting an error of `Undefined offset: 1` why?

**Code:**

```
function get_server_memory_usage(){

        $free = shell_exec('free');
        $free = (string)trim($free);
        $free_arr = explode("\n", $free);
        $mem = explode(" ", $free_arr[1]);
        $mem = array_filter($mem);
        $mem = array_merge($mem);
        $memory_usage = $mem[2]/$mem[1]*100;

        return $memory_usage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a little more detail in order to determine exactly why this isn't working, but here's a few quick things to check:

1) Is the server a Linux server?  This script won't run correctly on Windows.

2) The "free" command might not be aliased to the program correctly, or might not be installed at all.  To check this, run "free" on the command line and verify that there is an output.

3) The output of the "free" program might not be the same for your system.  This code is assuming there are several lines output when the command is run.  If there is only a single line output, then this error would make sense and you will need to paste the output in order for me to correct the above code.